# Como pegar informação de uma tr no código Html utilizando o HtmlAgilitypack do visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, html-agility-pack

Boa noite, 
Estou fazendo um projeto em C# no VisualStudio 2019 utilizando o HtmlAgillyPack para capturar informações do site https://www.infomoney.com.br/cotacoes/ibovespa/ que contem os valores da bolsa de valores.
Não sei quais elementos usar para chegar nas Tags que preciso, segue abaixo a foto do código html da pagina do meu código C#.

OBS: no meu programa estou usando um MessageBox.Show só para realizar os teste mais fácil, quando conseguir acessá-los armazenarei cada um na sua devida variável.

Não sei consegui acessar as 'tr' que estão dentro do meu 'tbody'.

Muito Obrigado desde já! [image: Html e Pagina]

[image: Codigo C#]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcelo, montei um exemplo aqui para você efetuar a leitura dos `td` mas será necessário que você efetue algumas tratativas que estão comentadas no código abaixo:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
{
    OptionFixNestedTags = true
};

// TODO Carregar o HTML dinamicamente através de um requisição
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(@"
    <div class=""col-12 col-lg-8"">
        <div class=""data-table-full"">
        <table id=""high"" class=""default-table active"">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ativo</th>
                    <th>Último (R$)</th>
                    <th>Var. Dia (%)</th>
                    <th>Val. Min (R$)</th>
                    <th>Val. Máx (R$)</th>
                    <th>Data</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td><a href=""https://www.infomoney.com.br/AZUL4"">AZUL4</a></td>
                <td>52,90</td>
                <td class=""positive"">1.13</td>
                <td>52,46</td>
                <td>53,55</td>
                <td>11:01 25/10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href=""https://www.infomoney.com.br/BBAS3"">BBAS3</a></td>
                <td>47,30</td>
                <td class=""positive"">0.76</td>
                <td>47,12</td>
                <td>48,05</td>
                <td>11:01 25/10</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    ");

var trs = htmlDoc
    .GetElementbyId("high")
    .ChildNodes
    .Where(a => a.Name == "tr");

foreach(var tr in trs)
{
    // TODO Aqui você precisará efetuar algumas tratativas:
    // Se dentro do TD houver um outro elemento, você precisará
    // descer mais um nível para pegar o innerText.
    if (tr.ChildNodes[1].Name == "a")
    {
        // Tratar o anchor
        var innerTextDoAnchor = tr.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
    }

    // Exemplo de como concatenar os InnerText
    string valoresDosTdsConcatenados = string.Join(", ", tr.ChildNodes.Select(a => a.InnerText));
}
```

Comment: O Xará, me salvou legal...
Deu certinho se código, obrigado pela atenção, foi de ótima ajuda.